# convert a HTML to a JS file so i can unit test using mocha.js

Tags: javascript

I am want to convert an HTML file to a JS file so i can run a unit test using Mocha.JS

what I am testing for is to see if there are any double quotes (") in the HTML document

I'm kinda at a loss after googling for a few hours so if anyone can help it would be very much appreciated

MAny thanks in advance

Comment: Hi. You cannot convert HTML to JS. Try to rephrase your problem so we can tackle it. Also give us some code examples.

Comment: ah ok that would be a good reason why I can't find anything :-) basically all i want to do is run a unit test to see if there are any double quotes in the HTML document

Comment: Daniel I've already posted an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want but I'll do my guess. This is node.js code:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const contents = fs.readFileSync('index.html')
const thereAreDoubleQuotesInHtmlFile = contents.includes('"')

// test (with some pseudo-assertion-library)
assertTrue(thereAreDoubleQuotesInHtmlFile)
```

Comment: thanks so much, can i make this look at a directory also?

Comment: Of course. But you are starting to ask for too much, probably, because it's hard for me to know all the requirements and specific circumstances. I mean these are fairly basics of node.js. In order to work with directory use `readDirSync`, there are plenty of examples you can find on the web.

Comment: You are welcome! If my answer helped, please select it as the best one.

Answer (score 0):

HTML and JavaScript are completely different things that serve completely different purposes. You can't convert one into the other.

If you want to test, from JavaScript, the contents of the HTML file, then write a test (in JavaScript) which **reads the HTML file** and then tests the resulting string (possibly after running it through a DOM parser so you can test using DOM methods).